# Showdialog and Focus (incredible)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, focus, showdialog

I noticed a strange problem in VB.NET 2010.

If I call `showdialog` in a `TextBox_LostFocus`, when I close the form it causes a Loop, but ONLY if I pass from the first textbox to the second USING THE MOUSE! If I use tab it works normally.

I show whith an example:

1. Create New project and create two forms, `form1` and `form2`
2. In form1, create two textboxes.
3. In the `textbox1.lostfocus`, paste the following code

VB.NET Code:

```
Dim f As New Form2
f.ShowDialog()
```

Now: the focus is on `textbox1`. Right?

- If you move to textbox2 with tab key, `form2` appears. If you close it it's all normal
- BUT if you move to `textbox2` using the mouse, `form2` appears and if you close it another `form2` appears, until 23 times when you get an exception

I workarounded it moving the "dim" statement in declaration area of form1, but anyone has an idea of why of that behaviour?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not incredible but expected.  ShowDialog should/will trigger a new LostFocus event

Comment: The LostFocus event is *very* dangerous.  The reason it is hidden in the designer.  Read the MSDN library article for Control.LostFocus for details.  Always use the Leave event instead.

Comment: It's true, I didn't read it before.

I tried and it worked well, thanks a lot !!